# Basics vectors of cartesian coordinate system and corresponding lie group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have read Basics vectors of cartesian coordinate system  $ (i,j,k) $ form lie algebra under the cross product, So my question is What type of lie group does this lie algebra generate on exponentiating the generators  $ (i,j,k) $

Comment: The Lie Algebra so constructed is $\mathfrak {so}(3)$, see, e.g., [this](https://math.wikia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Comment: Adding to @lulu's comment, compare also math.stackexchange.com/q/107611/96384. Note that $\mathfrak{su}_2$ is isomorphic to this Lie algebra. It is also the derived Lie algebra of the quaternions with commutator bracket. Hence, corresponding Lie groups are e.g. $SU(2)$, the unit (= norm-1-)quaternions, or $SO(3)$, which are all highly related to each other.

Comment: can anyone  give a simple answer,